# What container can one use to keep various liquids or substances that can then be thrown in combat?

Tags: science-based, weapons

Some background on this question, I thought it up when I read a story about an Alchemist MC who can make stuff like Health potions, flask of highly corrosive liquid, flask of highly flammable and volatile liquid et cetera et cetera...
and occasionally in combat he/she would throw them at annoying monsters.

Which is why I thought that wouldn't it be mildly dangerous to carry all those glass flasks in a large sack/backpack while running around on an adventure? Like, even if those fragile glass flasks, which break when thrown, don't shatter when they crash against each other and what happens when you fall and one of those flask of very corrosive stuff happen to break and proceeds to liquefy your back tenderly or someone shot a projectile at your backpack full of nice health potions, dangerous acid, poison, oil and slimy liquid.....
Which is why I wanted to think up a better way to keep all these nasty liquids et cetera. (In better containers, I just don't want it breaking when I'm running around saving fools.)

Basically all I need is a better container of sorts that doesn't break so easily that I risk my life by running around but still breaks or releases its contents when I panic throw it towards a Goblin (or anything else).

AND the container should be something that's possible to make at least before or during the Renaissance period OR if it's not possible then maybe before the 2000s :P

Also, if someone can come up with a way for the container to increase its area of effect (the area the container can spread its contents), I would be happy if it even had a quarter of the radius on XCOM 2 Acid grenades. If someone can also come up with a way to make the containers reusable that would be amazing too.

NO magic containers please, those are simple enough to think up. I'm looking for something that would work without magic.

Comment: Your requirements are "must break when hit hard, but must not break when hit hard" - as such this is unanswerable unless you allow some kind of intention reading performed by your container - but you disallowed magic.

Comment: How big is the radius of XCOM 2 Acid grenades? I have never played that game.

Comment: @Mołot actually the requirements are pretty easy, just the question isn't great. Really either the weaker container has to be in a stronger container ro protect it or it needs to be a sort of grenade.

Comment: Maybe something that is measuring its movement so that it realizes whether it's currently being thrown in an arc or hit with a hammer...

Comment: @Secespitus i thought about that, but I don't think electronic fits his setting very well, and magic is disqualified.

Comment: @Skye What you're asking for is a grenade.

Comment: Have a series of bladders, each of which is robust and "squishy" to hold their respective liquids. Have a "screw lock" on each that allows you to screw in a fragile flask, opening the bladder and allowing you to quickly pump the flask with the needed liquid. For the more caustic ones, perhaps you have two connected bladders of their inert precursors that mix when you fill the flask. No danger to the user necessary, nor is any of this "high tech." Completely doable with renaissance tech but high level chemistry... :)

Answer (score 3):

**A grenade**

Or, something akin to it. It's not necessary to have it acutally explode to release its content, you could open the shell via a spring mechanism after you arm it by removing some kind of safety-pin. You will obviously need to look at the filling, as it cannot corrode its shell- an advantage glas has is that it's not easily corrodable.

We did manufacture early bombs or chemical grenades made from cast Iron and filled with gun powder or with added chemicals like quicklime (a highly corrosive substance) as early as [1467](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grenade#Early_grenades)

Using gunpowder to disperse chemicals in the air has the added advantage of increasing the chance of contact with said chemical for the target.

However, these early bombs needed open fire to be armed/ignited.

Since we are talking pre-renaissance, maybe you could use a percussion cap to ignite the gunpowder, which is hit by a spring-loaded hammer, which in turn is secured by a safety pin.

**Cushion Shell**

You use something light like wood, fill it with a padding made from wool, cotton or paper, put the chemical flask inside and close it with clamps or rope. This way the flask wont get damaged during transport, but you could easily open this shell and either remove the flask and throw it, or throw it all together depending on the distance and the make of the shell. In the latter case you'll need to make sure that the shell will separate from the flask before it hits.

You could also use a pull rope you hold in your hand while throwing, which pulls open the shell after a certain distance, maybe a meter or two, at which point the unprotected glas flask will fly towards the target, shattering and releasing the chemicals upon impact.

**You can't have both**

Either you want to reuse it, or you want to shatter it, either solution disqualifies the other.

Answer (score 1):

Even modern grenades are shipped in packaging which cushions them from shock and temperature extremes, so as noted in several answers, the flasks will need to be individually wrapped and contained while being carried. This adds bulk and weight to your pack, so limiting the number of grenades you can carry, and unless you are fighting from a prepared position where you can unpack the flasks and place them in front of you, there will be additional time to dig through the pack, unpackaged the flasks and so on.

That being said, glazed ceramic flasks might be somewhat more suitable for the job than glass. They are still brittle and need careful handling, but are cheaper to manufacture, can be made in large numbers by relatively unskilled labour (the local king or warlord might appreciate this) and only need a supply of clay to make, which is easier to find than the various materials and high temperature fuels needed for glass making. Ceramics are also brittle, and with low velocity explosives should break into large, razor edged fragments similar to shrapnel.

The other thing you might consider is using some sort of binary trigger. In your case, adding quicklime to water should start a furious boiling reaction, creating essentially a steam grenade. Other combinations are possible (although less likely using medieval technology), with the ultimate being the sorts of binary chemicals used for [hypergolic](https://infogalactic.com/info/Hypergolic_propellant) rocket fuel (the two substances ignite on contact). Assuming you handwave some sort of alchemical discovery of hypergolic fuels, then having a flask with one chemical and inserting smaller flask inside with the second chemical prior to throwing would make an astounding grenade (the ceramic pieces will fly out as an effective shrapnel, and the ball of flame will also be damaging), but a lot of dangerous experimentation will be needed to create the right mix and find safe ways to carry and prepare the device.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see for a shattering grenade-type object to be reusable would be if you imagined some kind of electromagnetism that reassembled the object after its initial explosion, such that it could then be refilled and reused.

If you are happy to invent such a thing within your story of course.

Answer (score 0):

A really good backpack that is well cushioned is the best idea if you don't want magic or tech that is way beyond what they had in the renaissance.